# How To Calculate Expression in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like below:

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

How can I calculate ID PAY2 formula value of empid E001. Calculate like: `parameter1 = basic` and basic of `E001 = 1000`.

So as per formula `if PAY1>4000 then PAY5` (may be value is 200 of parameter5)

So for E001 basic is 1000 and it is false against if condition and value should be `{PAY1}/100` like `1000/100=10`.

Is it possible to execute if and else condition in a column and calculate its value?

Comment: You might want to use [`EXEC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Your path leads to doom - start over. Your first problem is that you have no foreign key between the tables. You have PAYDID = 1 in the 2nd table and that appears to be a "pointer" of sorts to the row in the 1st table where ID = PAY1. So what happens when you have a row with PAYID = 22 in the 2nd table? Don't assume it will never happen. Ignoring that flaw, you will need to implement your own language (so that you can store only "understood" values in 1st table) and then dynamically parse and calculate the desired value from that text.

Comment: You could use a CASE Statement, e.g. CASE WHEN PAYNAME = 'BASIC' AND PAY1>4000 THEN PAY5 ELSE PAY1 END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to be able to embed formulae within your database, and execute those formulae to calculate pay.

This is a hard problem to solve - you're basically trying to implement a min programming language in SQL.

I assume you want this feature because the business rules may change (or at least the parameters) and you don't want to have to spend developer time when that happens.

If you can express the formulae as SQL, you can use [dynamic SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) (the exec feature), but this may be error prone, and subject to abuse - if you allow people to store executable SQL code as data, a small bug in that code could wipe out all your data. It's also hard to test.

It's very likely that developers would have to write the dynamic SQL statements anyway, so you're unlikely to achieve your goal.

If you can distinguish between "algorithm" and "parameters", you could make those parameters editable by non-technical users, and only need to involve developers when the algorithm changes. You could store the parameters in a database table (and give them better names than "parameter_n"). This is one of the few occasions when an [entity/attribute/value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) store makes sense, though it would be better to encode this as XML or JSON in the database, as that would allow you to declare a schema (and test against it!).

Your example might become:

```
select @allowance = (
      select value 
      from parameters 
      where key = 'default_allowance') 
  where pay > (
      select value 
      from parameters 
      where key = 'min_pay_for_allowance');
select @allowance = pay / (
                    select value 
                    from parameters 
                    where key = 'pay_divisor_for_allowance) 
 where pay <= (
            select value 
            from parameters 
            where key = 'min_pay_for_allowance');
```